# Can't find Google Play Service in extras folder

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services

Using Eclipse, I want to use Google Play Service library.
So I had to copy **Android\sdk\extras\google\google-play-services** folder in my workspace and then set this project as library in my project.

Unfortunatly, this folder do not exists on my computer.

When I open *Android SDK Manager*, in *Extras* section, *Google Play Services* appears as **Installed**.

Comment: what about searching your disk for that folder?

Comment: already try, not found on disk.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling it in the SDK? I can't find anything similar to your questions since there's a lot of questions about Google Play Services missing on the SDK Manager. Hopefully an update and admin privileges will be the only reasons for it not being "installed"

Comment: I had similar problem and found solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37381152/2240880