# Google play services installed but folder google_play_services_lib not exists

Tags: android, qt, android-studio, google-play-games

I have stupid question, but I can't resolve my problem ((
I'm user Android SDK manager revision 25.1.6
Google play services installed (folder Sdk\extras\google\google_play_services exists), but google_play_services_lib folder not exists in SDK folder
I tried reinstall play services but with the same result
In folder google_play_services only docs, samples and package.xml source.properties
maybe somebody has solution for this problem?
Thank you

-- edit
create simple project in android studio
add line "compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'"
project build successfully but I still can't found google_play_services_lib folder

I need this folder to include to my Qt project

Comment: You should be using Gradle to acquire the Google play services dependencies.

Comment: add in to gradle // Google Play Services
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'

Comment: it's work but I need compiled lib to include into another project

Comment: For compatibility, the Google Play libraries are stored in a maven-compatible file structure in *$sdk\extras\google\m2repository*

Comment: exactly) I found it thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

google_play_services-lib is installed using the Android SDK manager.  It is under the extras section called "Google Play Services".

You really should try not to use the google_play_services-lib any longer if you can avoid it.  It contains the entire client library for google play services which is very large, and in most cases, your application is only using a small portion of the client SDK.

A better solution for your non-gradle project is to expand the .aar files you need (you can rename them .zip files or use `jar xf <aarfile>` to expand them.

You can find them in the extras/google/m2repository directory, broken down by package name.  In the same directory as the .aar file, there is a .pom file which is an XML file.  At the end of that file there is a list of dependencies - you'll need to expand those as well.

This way you will have only the smallest set of dependencies for your app.